# $\min(a,b,c) \leq p a + (1-2p)b + pc \leq \max(a,b,c)$

Tags: analysis, inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be all positive, $p \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ (it should be interpreted as a probability).
Prove that
$$\min(a,b,c) \leq p a + (1-2p)b + pc \leq \max(a,b,c)$$

#### My attempt

Some sanity checks: if $p=0$ we have 
$$\min(a,b,c) \leq b \leq \max(a,b,c)$$ 
which is true, so that's good.

If $p=\frac{1}{2}$, we have 
$$ \min(a,b,c) \leq \frac{a + c}{2} \leq \max(a,b,c)$$
I can prove this: 
$$\frac{a+c}{2} \geq a \iff c \geq a \iff a = \min(a,c) \geq \min(a,b,c) $$ and similarly for $c$. The proof for the $\max$ should be similar. Also, logically, the average of two numbers should be between those numbers. So far so good.

Now, to tackle the main problem, assume a general $p$. 
$$ pa + (1-2p)b + pc \geq a \iff (1-2p)b + pc \geq a(1-p)$$
but I am blocked at this stage. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### Solution

As explained in the accepted answer, the expression ca be seen as a linear function $f(p)$ in $p$, so the minimum and the maximum are at the boundaries of $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$, so we can reuse my proof above and we are done.

*Edit*: for an even simpler solution see my comment under one of the other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint: interpret the expression as a function in $p$:

$$f(p)=b+p(a-2b+c).$$

This is linear in $p$, so it reaches its smallest and largest points on the interval $[0,1/2]$ at its two endpoints...

Answer (score 2):

For non-negative coefficients $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma$, and non-negative reals $a,b,c$, we have

$$ (\alpha + \beta + \gamma) \min (a , b, c) \leq   \alpha a + \beta b + \gamma c \leq (\alpha + \beta + \gamma) \max(a,b,c)$$

Apply this to $ \alpha = p, \beta = 1-2p, \gamma = p$.

Comment: Hi, which middle do you refer to here ? Thanks

Comment: I added details. Am on mobile so hard to edit. This is essentially a one-liner.

Comment: Very neat: $(p+1-2p +p)\min(a,b,c) \leq p \min(a,b,c) + (1-2p) \min(a,b,c) + p \min(a,b,c) \leq p a + (1-2p)b + pc$.

Comment: Yes indeed. I've edited the writeup now.

Comment: Maybe use the words "barycentric coefficients" for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ with respect to "points" $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 1):

The geometric interpretation:
$pa+(1-2p)b+pc$ is a convex combination of $a,b,c$ when $0\leq p\leq1/2$,the result follows.